# Creating an arm skeleton with more than 3 bones with Rigify

Tags: rigging, armature

For some reason I'm trying to create a skeleton for a model with an arm made of 5 bones with Rigify, but Rigify is throwing an error message that there can't be more than 3 bones for an arm. 2 bones are supposed to behave like a normal bone, as if there is no joint between them, i.e. 2 bones + 2 bones + 1 bone. is there a way to convert this to Rigify without reducing the bone count?

[image: custom arm]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, Rigify works using premade modules it can recognize and generate a rig from. You can customize the modules with whatever options given by Rigify, but you can't make up your modules (not without programming them into Rigify).

[Rigify — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/addons/rigging/rigify/index.html)

If your goal is to have each section of an arm to be made out of two deform bones, know that this is already the case by default:

If you select the top-level bone of a chain in Pose Mode, you can see the Rigify Type and its settings. By selecting one of the `upper_arm`, you can see that it is preset to generate two "segments" :

[image: preset]

The resulting rig will have two bones in the arm and forearm:

[image: generated rig]

You can find many other options as such, as well as different Rigify Types that might better suit your needs.

[Limbs - limbs.arm — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/limbs.html#limbs-arm)

If you want to do something for which Rigify doesn't provide a module, I.E. an arm with two elbows, you can't do it out of the box. You would need to learn some Python and add your own modules to Rigify programmatically.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Is it possible to assign X and Z rotation to one of these two bones (segments) and Y rotation to the other? so my goal is to make different weight paint for "XZ" and "Y" rotations.